# what is the best way to store user created data?

Tags: database

The plan is for users to be able to store locations and have notes and other variables for each location. These locations would later be shown on a map, so I would need to be able to quickly access the data also. I was just wondering what the best way to go about this would be before I try to get things set up with the map api so I don't have to go back and change everything later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should store additional user data in `wp_usermeta` table. For that, use [add_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) function. Here's an example of how you can store locations

```
$location = array('name'   => 'example location name',
                  'street' => 'example street name',
                  'note'   => 'example user note'
                 );
add_user_meta($user_id, 'location', $location);
```

You can store as many locations as you want. To retrieve the locations use [get_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) They will be returned as array of locations.

```
$locations = get_user_meta($user_id, 'location');
foreach($locations as $location) {
    echo $location['name'];
}
```

To update a particular location, you can use [update_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta). But it's a little tricky as every location will have the same `meta_key` named `location`. So, you need to also send the previous `meta_value` to let Wordpress know exactly which row you want to update. Here's a example to update a location with street name `abcd street`

```
foreach($locations as $location) {
    if($location['street'] = 'abcd street') {
        $new_location = array('name'   => 'Modified location',
                              'street' => 'Modified street',
                              'note'   => 'Modified Note'
                             );
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'location', $new_location, $location);
    }
}
```